# Convert single mbox file from Mac OS to linux courier mailbox format

Tags: linux, email, courier, mbox

I have a MAC OS `mbox` file. Each user has his own folder and each folder has a file named `mbox` in it.  How can I convert this single large `mbox` file to individual email files, like the directory structure readable by courier imap server?

Answer (score 1):

Search google for "mbox to maildir conversion". This is one of the hits:http://untroubled.org/mbox2maildir - as I remember, the one I used when I had to do a similar migration.